# How to use a data from one table as a reference to get another data in another table using Firebase?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I just retrieve a list of data from a table named 'appointment'. From this table, I will need to get a data named 'theraid' in order to get the name from another table named 'thera'. I have no idea how to do it in android java. Is there someone can guide me? Thanks in advance.

Here is my table structure in firebase
[image: table]

Here is my code, but it does not work for me.
Java class

```
 databaseReference= FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointment");

        databaseReference.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(userid1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {


                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                    AppointmentObject thera= dataSnapshot1.getValue(AppointmentObject.class);
                    String tid = dataSnapshot.child("theraid").getValue(String.class);

                    a.add(thera);

                     refThera = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("alluser").child("thera");
                    refThera.child(tid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                            for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot2: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                String text = dataSnapshot2.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                                tname.add(text);

                        }}

                        @Override
                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            throw databaseError.toException();
                        }
                    });
                }


            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        adapter=new MyRecyclerviewPAppointment(MainActivityPAppointment.this, a,tname);
        rv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

RecyclerView class

```
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final MyRecyclerviewPAppointment.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.tname.setText(name.get(position).charAt(position));
        holder.tdate.setText(alist.get(position).getDate());
        holder.ttime.setText(alist.get(position).getTiming());

    }
```

Comment: have you tried the answer?

Comment: haven yet,  tomorrow i will try :) thank you so much

Comment: I have edited my question to the lastest code.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child(), i think it cannot get the theraid

Comment: @PeterHaddad, sorry for disturbing, I have tried to add another for loop inside the second database reference but it seems still the same.

Comment: check my edit in the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
 databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("appointment");

        databaseReference.orderByChild("userid").equalTo(userid1).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot1: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    String theraid = dataSnapshot1.child("theraid").getValue(String.class);

                    DatabaseReference refThera = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("alluser").child("thera");
                    refThera.child(theraid).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                   public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                       String name = dataSnapshot.child("name").getValue(String.class);
                       }

                    @Override
                 public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                      throw databaseError.toException(); 
                    }
              });


               }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Oh no!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                throw databaseError.toException();
            }
        });
```

First retreive the `theraid` inside the `appointment` node then add another `databaseReference` and use the `theraid` to be able to retrieve the `name`.

Comment: Now I receive an error 'java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.Object java.util.ArrayList.get(int)' on a null object reference' in Recyclerview class, may I know how to get the String? I stored the name that retrieved from firebase into an ArrayList named 'name' in the Recyclerview class.

Comment: Is it the way I retrieve it from the ArrayList is wrong?

Comment: There is no `get()` in my answer

Comment: I think there's something wrong to the Recyclerview class. Thank you sir for helping me :)